# How to count the consecutive occurrence of a time segment? - Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
datetime              levels       shear
2016-05-01 00:10:00    100           5
2016-05-01 00:10:00    200           6 
2016-05-01 00:10:00    300           10
2016-05-01 00:10:00    400           11
2016-05-01 00:20:00    100           7  
2016-05-01 00:20:00    300           10
2016-05-01 00:30:00    100           5
2016-05-01 00:30:00    200           9
2016-05-01 00:30:00    300           12
2016-05-01 00:30:00    400           15
2016-05-01 00:40:00    100           19
2016-05-01 00:40:00    200           2
2016-05-01 00:40:00    300           18
```

which is the wind shear at different altitudes per 10 minutes interval.

What i am trying to do is to group it by levels, then calculate the consecutive occurrence of shear for each level. So, first i create another column which is the time difference of each successive data group by levels:

```
data3_5['Delta'] = data3_5.sort_values(['levels','datetimes']).groupby('levels')['datetimes'].diff()
```

then define a function to perform rolling count for successive occurrence of same time difference:

```
  def rolling_count(val):
    if val == rolling_count.previous:
       rolling_count.count +=1
    else:
       rolling_count.previous = val
       rolling_count.count = 1
  return rolling_count.count
 rolling_count.count = 0 #static variable
 rolling_count.previous = None #static variable
```

applying the function and add a new column:

```
data3_5['count'] = data3_5.sort_values(['levels','datetimes']).groupby('levels')['index'].diff().apply(rolling_count)
```

then finally print out the result:

```
group = data3_5.groupby('levels', as_index=False)
group_keys = sorted(list(group.groups.keys()))

for each in range(0,len(group_keys)):
    group_result = group.get_group(group_keys[each])
    print(group_result)
```

the following is part of the result:

```
datetime              levels  shear  Delta     count
2016-05-01 00:10:00   100     5      NaT       1
2016-05-01 00:20:00   100     7      00:10:00  1
2016-05-01 00:30:00   100     5      00:10:00  2
2016-05-01 00:40:00   100     19     00:10:00  3
datetime              levels  shear  Delta     count
2016-05-01 00:10:00   200     6      NaT       1
2016-05-01 00:30:00   200     9      00:20:00  1
2016-05-01 00:40:00   200     2      00:10:00  1
```

This is not the desired result as there will be two problems:
1. The first count for each level will be treated as NaT, therefore the next successive occurrence of values will be treated as the first occurrence.
2. similar to that of problem 1, for level 200, the third result should be counted as 2.

How can i fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

First let's make sure df['datetime'] really is datetime object:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df['Delta'] = df.groupby('levels')['datetime'].transform(lambda x: x-x.shift(1))
df['count'] = df.groupby('levels')['Delta'].transform(lambda x : x.le(pd.Timedelta('10 minutes')).cumsum())
df.sort_values(by='levels')
```

Output:

```
              datetime  levels  shear    Delta  count
0  2016-05-01 00:10:00     100      5      NaT      0
4  2016-05-01 00:20:00     100      7 00:10:00      1
6  2016-05-01 00:30:00     100      5 00:10:00      2
10 2016-05-01 00:40:00     100     19 00:10:00      3
1  2016-05-01 00:10:00     200      6      NaT      0
7  2016-05-01 00:30:00     200      9 00:20:00      0
11 2016-05-01 00:40:00     200      2 00:10:00      1
2  2016-05-01 00:10:00     300     10      NaT      0
5  2016-05-01 00:20:00     300     10 00:10:00      1
8  2016-05-01 00:30:00     300     12 00:10:00      2
12 2016-05-01 00:40:00     300     18 00:10:00      3
3  2016-05-01 00:10:00     400     11      NaT      0
9  2016-05-01 00:30:00     400     15 00:20:00      0
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, your solution is very clear and straight forward, i will give it a try. I think to directly append the groupby result as a new column into the original dataframe will be much better than obtaining the groupby result afterwards using get_group, what is more difficult to deal with, what is your suggestion?